# Php session not storing on webhost

Tags: php

I made a simple session and works flawlessly on my localhost (xampp)

the first page is something like this

```
<?php 
     if(!session_start()):
        session_start();
     endif;
?>

<?php
$_SESSION['user'] = "grace1004";
echo '<a href = "2ndpage.php">Please Click</a>';
?>
```

2nd page

```
<?php
     if(!session_start()):
        session_start();
     endif;
     ?>
     <?php
if($_SESSION['user']) {
echo $_SESSION['user'];
}
else {
    echo ' hahahaha'; //i made this to check if the session is being stored
}

?>
```

im using 000webhostapp and the error says undefined index: user

Comment: Your code reads `if(!session_start()) session_start()`, so basically, if the session fails to start, you just try again? If it didn't start first time, it probably won't start the second.

Comment: @PrateikDarji suggesting to use error suppression is not a good strategy at all.

Comment: `if (!session_start())` does *not* mean "if session is not started". What you're writing is *"if starting the session failed, start the session."* You're just doing the same thing twice.

Comment: im receiving this error Use of undefined constant start_session - assumed 'start_session'

Comment: i already tried just writing the session_start(); and it still won't work

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
session_start();
    
    
if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
echo $_SESSION['user'];
}
else {
    echo ' hahahaha'; //i made this to check if the session is being stored
}

?>
```

you shoud use  session_start(); at the beginning of each php file you need to use a session 
try this !